# Strange problems after adding the function

Tags: c, function, microcontroller

I have strange problem. When I compile first function, microcontroller send signal with bugs (som octet are duplicate, some are not sent at all e.t.c.). But when I compite second function, microcontroller sending clear signal. What could be the reason for these bugs? If you need more information, I will try to answer :3

---

First function:

```
uint8_t DataOut[DATA_OUT_BUF_SIZE];
uint8_t DataOutPosition = 0;

void add_data(uint8_t Value)
{
    DataOut[DataOutPosition] = Value;
    DataOutPosition++;
}

void send_data()
{
    uint8_t Checksum = 0x52;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < DataOutPosition; ++i)
    {
        Checksum ^= DataOut[i];
    }
    
    add_data((checksum_compression(Checksum) | (ProcessDataStatus << 6) | (EventFlag << 7)));
    
    UART_CONTROL &= ~(1 << RXEN0);
    EN_OUT;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < DataOutPosition; ++i)
    {
        uart_put(DataOut[i]);
    }
    default_variables();
}
```

---

Second function:

```
uint8_t DataOut[DATA_OUT_BUF_SIZE];
uint8_t DataOutPosition = 0;

void send_data()
{
    uint8_t Checksum = 0x52;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < DataOutPosition; ++i)
    {
        Checksum ^= DataOut[i];
    }
    
    DataOut[DataOutPosition] = checksum_compression(Checksum) | (ProcessDataStatus << 6) | (EventFlag << 7);
    DataOutPosition++;
    
    UART_CONTROL &= ~(1 << RXEN0);
    EN_OUT;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < DataOutPosition; ++i)
    {
        uart_put(DataOut[i]);
    }
    default_variables();
}
```

---

Description:

- 1 - Signal generated by the first function.
- 2 - Signal generated by the second function.
- B - Received signal. (One communication bus. When the microcontroller sends a signal, it simultaneously receives it.)
- Y - Sent signal by the microcontroller.
- R - Signal direction: 0-IN 1-OUT

[Logic analyzer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PPvz.png)

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies elsewhere.  Or perhaps the stack size is not large enough and the extra call to `add_data()` is enough to overflow the stack.

Comment: But add_data() is fourth function in stack. How to check the stack size during microcontroller operation?

Comment: If I read your problem description right, your code _does_ compile, and _runs_, but it is buggy for some reason.  Have you run it in a debugger and steps through.

Comment: No, because i don't have debugger :/

Comment: what compiler?  (many have debuggers available for free)

Comment: When behavior changes by seemingly unrelated code changes, then that is often caused by undefined behavior. @kkrambo already mentioned stack overflow. Another possibility is buffer overflow. Could it be `DataOutPosition` exceeds `DATA_OUT_BUF_SIZE`? By the way, how is `checksum_compression` defined?

Comment: This program it is communication between Atmega1284P and PLC using IO-Link protocol. This bug appears during data exchange between master and device. No, `DataOutPosition` not exceeds `DATA_OUT_BUF_SIZE`, because at this stage of the project maximum vaule of send data is 2 and `DATA_OUT_BUF_SIZE = 32`. I think stack overflow is impossible because program is small compared to Atmega and none of the functions is recursive. `checksum_compression()` it is function where 8bit variables are compressed to 6bit.

Comment: Do you have an ISR around which changes `DataOutPosition`?  Just add `volatile` to the two globals. Do you observe a different behaviour of your two variants? Based on the code you shared with us that shouldn't be the case.